# Where is the syntax error in this sql query?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, postgis

I'm working with PostGIS and spatial data types from VB, and I have this insert query, which I use to save the data of the marker that is placed on the map (I want to save the latitude and longitude of the marker placed on the map in the database). I tried to use "double" and "decimal", but this is the most "professional" way to save coordinates I think..

> ```
> $"insert into personas values ('" & idpers & "','" & txtNombre.Text & "','" & txtApe.Text & "','" & txtTel.Text & "','" & txtDire.Text & "','" & cboxZona.SelectedItem & "',ST_GeomFromText('POINT('" & txtLatBD.Text & "' '" & txtLngBD.Text & "')'))"
> ```

I think I'm missing a symbol somewhere, but I don't see where. When I insert the same data from the console, it works fine..

Comment: That has not been the correct way to put SQL together for a long time.  You are not specifying which "values" map to which column and passing everything as text.  use SQL parameters.  Always.  Also please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I think I'm going to throw up some SQL injection right now.

Answer (score 1):

@Plutonix is correct - but in response to your syntax error question, you appear to have extra quotes:
example:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-70.060544 40.28707)');
```

yours (numbers replacing variables):

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT('-70.060544' '40.28707')')
```

yours (fixed with variables):

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(" & txtLatBD.Text & " " & txtLngBD.Text & ")')
```

Reference for the Constructor: http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html

Comment: When I do that, It appears a Msgbox that says "Invalid GIS data provided to function  st_geometryfromtext". The data saved in the txtLatBD.Text and txtLngBD.Text is Double. Perhaps I should convert the data to another datatype before I execute the query?

Comment: Try just writing out the query to the screen instead of running it so you can see what you're getting.  Then you can take that and run it directly on the DB as well